# Why PostMessage has no effect when called from within a global hotkey handler?

Tags: winapi

A GUI app I'm writing does send a keydown event to another window, a `cmd.exe`.

```
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
```

The event is sent just fine when it's done on events like `WM_CREATE`, `WM_KEYUP`, etc (a new line appears in `cmd.exe`).

Then I setup a global hotkey with `RegisterHotKey`. In a `WM_HOTKEY` handler I successfully receive key presses but `PostMessage` has no effect anymore.

How to fix that?

Full example, minified as possible:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

BOOL CALLBACK enumWindows(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {
    char winTitle[1024*10];
    GetWindowText(hwnd, winTitle, sizeof(winTitle));
    if (strstr(winTitle, "cmd.exe") != NULL) {
        cout << "Sending a message to window " << hwnd << ": " << winTitle << endl;
        PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0);
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(msg) {
        case WM_CREATE:
            // register hotkey ctrl+alt+s
            RegisterHotKey(hwnd, 100, MOD_ALT | MOD_CONTROL, 'S');
            break;
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            EnumWindows(enumWindows, 0);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        case WM_HOTKEY:
            // hotkey ctrl+alt+s fired
            EnumWindows(enumWindows, 0);
            break;
        case WM_KEYUP:
            EnumWindows(enumWindows, 0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// just init stuff, do not waste your time
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG Msg;

    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style         = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra    = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra    = 0;
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName  = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, g_szClassName, "Test", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

Windows 7 64-bit

Comment: Perhaps the `WM_KEYDOWN` handler checks the state of other keys, which are depressed at the instant the hotkey fires?

Comment: Faking input, and doing it wrong, is, well, wrong. You might have better success using the official automation interface: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Raymond Chen has documented why this doesn't work the way you expect (`PostMessage` IS working just fine, but the response of the other window depends on actual keyboard state, just as I surmised in my comment).  See his blog post:

- [You can't simulate keyboard input with `PostMessage`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx)